# nintendo 64 emulation, confused with mupen 64pluse/m64py, project 64 freezes

Tags: wine, 64-bit, emulation

I'm in a huge pickle. I'm trying to help a friend to whom I installed Linux for. He is happy with it since he gave up that old xp. but the problem now that we are both faced with is playing our 64 games on Linux. I installed project 64 through wine and it works at first but at a certian point it the frame rates drop dramaticly. him and I both have integrated 256 mbs intel graphics cards wich n64 should run very smoothly on.
but anyway thinking that some sort of compatibility issue with directx9 in wine or something, I tried to install mupen64plus, and found myself not so happy that it is in command line I attempted to find a front end. I installed m64py, and it opens but it wants all these plugins, to wich I thought I had it all setup, then it wants a library file. I do not know where to look for one. I tried to google one. and save for compiling crap no dice. I do not want to compile a program I AM NOT A PROGRAMER. I am a linux newb and I am tryying to keep it basic. Please help me. please help me friend. Thank you.

Comment: Older versions of mupen64plus had a graphical user interface, try using an old package.

Answer (score 1):

Thats ok. I figured it out. turns out all I needed to do was install m64py and download mupen64plus in parts. unzipped the tarballs into folders and told m64py what directories they go in. Took a while to figure out but I am glad I did